# reflection: private property how to extract custom attribute

Tags: c#, custom-attributes

Hi it's possible to retrieve custom attribute in private property

```
   public class TestAttr
    {
        [SaveInState]
        protected string testPrivate { get { return "test private"; }  }
        [SaveInState]
        public string testPublic { get{ return "test public"; }}

        public IDictionary<string, object> dumpVars()
        {

            IDictionary<string, object> dict = new Dictionary<string, object>();

            Type ownerClassType = this.GetType();


            foreach (var mi in ownerClassType.GetProperties(BindingFlags.NonPublic))
            {

                var varAttrib = Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(mi, typeof(SaveInStateAttribute));
                if (varAttrib != null)
                {
                    dict.Add(mi.Name, mi.GetValue(this, null));
                }
            }

            return dict;

        }
    }
```

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is perfectly possible. The code you have (while a little pointless since you don't need reflection since you're working in your own type) is pretty close:

```
var type = this.GetType();
foreach(var prop in 
    type.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic))
{
    var attr = prop.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(SaveInStateAttribute), true);

    if(attr.Length > 0)
    {
        // Add the attributes to your collection
    }
}
```

Comment: great! thanks it works..., yes you right but inside class isn't needed reflection but is just an examples thanks